# Python 2.7 Mailchimp3 401 status "API Key is missing"

Tags: python, request, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am currently trying to make a call using mailchimp3:

```
client.reports.email_activity.all(campaign_id = '#######', getall=True, fields = '######')
```

When I call large amounts of email data I get the 401 status error. I am able to call smaller amounts with no error.

I tried increasing:

```
request.get(timeout=10000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling large amounts of data in one call can cause this timeout error. Instead it is best to use the offset method.

```
client.reports.email_activity.all(campaign_id = '#####', offset = #, count = #, fields = '######')
```

With this you can loop through and make a bunch of smaller calls instead of one large call that causes the timeout issue.

Thanks to the support staff at chimp mail that helped me trouble shoot this issue.